# ValueError: values are all NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, nan

can anyone please tell where i am going wrong in the code, because values are all coming NaN which i dont want. I want to have a series of average high of 25 previous RSIndex values( you can consider it as lookback period) for each RSIndex value.

```
def AvgHigh(ser, src, cnt, val) :
    total = 0.0
    count = 0
    for i in (0, ser) :
        for a in range(i, i+cnt) :
            if src[a] > val :
                count = count + 1
                total = total + src[a]
            elif src[a] <= val :
                count = count + 0
                total = total + 0
        return round(total / count)

df['RSI_high'] = pd.Series(AvgHigh(len(df['RSIndex']), df['RSIndex'], 25, 52)).fillna(0)
```

[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/432qj.png)

Comment: `AvgHigh` returns exactly one value.  What were you expecting it to do?  Is it possible you meant to use `yield` instead of `return`, so that you return one value per item in the series?  If so, then you also want `for i in range(ser):` instead of just iterating through two values.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim, yes thats what i meant, i wanted to have a ref high value for each item, so yield was indeed of great help, and yes, i missed out on range function, but when i am running again, it is giving me a keyError

Comment: len(df['RSIndex]) is 29983


`File "C:\Users\RAHUL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 353, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 29983`

Comment: You can see why, can't you?  There are 29983 items in the list.  When you get to item 29982, you're still looking ahead 25 items, which runs right off the end of the list.  Perhaps your range should be `range(ser-cnt)`.

Comment: Thank you so much @TimRoberts, ya this thing worked, cheers

Answer (score 0):

- you really don't need to do looping, can very simply be vectorised
- first filter to rows that are greater than value specified
- reduce using `head()` to number of rows you want
- then it's just the `mean()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"RSIndex":np.random.uniform(61,68,200)})

# really don't need length of series, so "ser" argument is redundant    
def AvgHigh(ser, src, cnt, val):
    return src.loc[src.gt(val)].head(cnt).mean()

# df['RSI_high'] = pd.Series(AvgHigh(len(df['RSIndex']), df['RSIndex'], 25, 52)).fillna(0)
df['RSI_high'] = AvgHigh(len(df['RSIndex']), df['RSIndex'], 25, 52)
df
```

#### sample out

|  | RSIndex | RSI_high |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 65.9272 | 65.0022 |
| 1 | 67.5969 | 65.0022 |
| 2 | 63.9528 | 65.0022 |
| 3 | 67.0719 | 65.0022 |
| 4 | 64.2278 | 65.0022 |
| 5 | 64.9158 | 65.0022 |
| 6 | 66.0637 | 65.0022 |
| 7 | 66.3771 | 65.0022 |
| 8 | 66.9548 | 65.0022 |
| 9 | 63.3385 | 65.0022 |

Comment: Thanks @RobRaymond for bringing out an efficient way, i tried this but this is giving me only the mean of top 25 rows of the whole dataframe because of which the end value that i m getting is same throughout the dataframe, i wanted kind of rolling mean thing with window 25, which changes in ref to RSIndex values